# Does Rust have bindings for tee(2)?

Tags: linux, io, rust

Does Rust have bindings for `tee(2)` in `std::io` or otherwise? And if there are no bindings, how would I get that functionality in a Rust program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tee` method [existed in the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.6.0/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.tee), but [it was deprecated in 1.6](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/30187).

You can use [the tee crate](https://crates.io/crates/tee) to get the same functionality:

```
extern crate tee;

use tee::TeeReader;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let mut reader = "It's over 9000!".as_bytes();
    let mut teeout = Vec::new();
    let mut stdout = Vec::new();
    {
        let mut tee = TeeReader::new(&mut reader, &mut teeout);
        let _ = tee.read_to_end(&mut stdout);
    }
    println!("tee out -> {:?}", teeout);
    println!("std out -> {:?}", stdout);
}
```

([example from the repo](https://github.com/softprops/tee/blob/42e9fc6ee/examples/simple.rs))